# Xamarin CarouselView ios blank page

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have installed the CarouselView plugin via nuget in my solution.

I load the ItemSource of the CarouselView with a List of DataTemplate.
In Android and UWP works like a charm, but in iOs nothing is showed.

This is the c# code for loading the ItemSource:

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {

        base.OnAppearing();    

        AggiungiRigaWOViewModel _AggiungiRigaWOViewModel = new AggiungiRigaWOViewModel(_WoSelezionato);                                                                                                                 

        MyDataTemplateSelector tmpl = new MyDataTemplateSelector();

        carouselView.Position = 0;
        carouselView.ItemsSource = tmpl.ListOfTemplate; // ListOfTemplate is a List<DataTemplate>.

        BindingContext = _AggiungiRigaWOViewModel; 
        UpdateViewModel(_AggiungiRigaWOViewModel);   
    }

}
```

The XAML page has this code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <carouselView:CarouselViewControl
                ShowIndicators="True"
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                IndicatorsTintColor="#ffd800"
                CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="#ffad00"
                InterPageSpacing="10" 
                ShowArrows="True"
                AnimateTransition="True"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                x:Name="carouselView"  >          
            </carouselView:CarouselViewControl>
</StackLayout>
```

If I run this code on Android or UWP It works, but in iOs only a blank page is shown.

How can I make this code works on IOS?

[Project files](https://ufile.io/h9446)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your project, it was caused by the missing code : `CarouselViewRenderer.Init()` in iOS project.

**Solution**: Add the code in AppDelegate in iOS project.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options) {
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    CarouselViewRenderer.Init();   //Add this line.
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  that  you have  installed the `Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView` plugin in **PCL**, **.Droid** and **.IOS**

Comment: Hi, I have installed it via gitHub inside Visual Studio 2017, and I have check all project before installing. Also I have checked all references in all projects and the plugin is correctly installed.

Comment: check in IOS , in the packages folder , is `Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView` there ?

Comment: Hi, there is the image of all references in my project:
PCL: https://ufile.io/z6m0l, android: https://ufile.io/fuggz, ios: https://ufile.io/bpglt, UWP: https://ufile.io/cl69g. 
And this i the nuget package that I have installed (Latest version 4.4.6): https://ufile.io/eqokr.
Thank you.